# How to access the Linux VM in Azure

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, windows-7, virtual-machine

My Project requires me to access a Linux VM which is on Azure.
I can access it using *putty* (for *ssh*) on my **home network**.
But in my **company network**, i cant access the VM.

**Problem** - As per my understanding, i don't have port access.
The network admin says, he can grant me permission for particular IP.

**Question** - Is it possible to give the VM a static IP.

**NOTE** - My client is Windows 7. And the VM is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You can buy a reserved public ip. Here is [the document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/)

Comment: @JackZeng i will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Is it possible to give an Azure instance a static public IP?

A: Sure - but you'll probably have to pay extra for it:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/

Note, too, that you need a *public* static IP.  This is something only the folks at Microsoft can give you.

If this project is for your company, then your company's network admin probably needs to find another way to open a port for you.

ADDENDUM:

Here is one other suggestion: reverse SSH port forwarding:

- https://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding/
- https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling

Comment: thanks.. can you suggest me something for the network admin also.

Comment: By the way i am accepting it as answer but can you suggest me something for port access also.

Comment: Your network admin should know best what alternatives are available to him - they can and will vary from site to site.  Here are a couple of possibilties: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/working-with-firewall-protected-server-through-ssh-dynamic-ip or https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-can-resellers-w-dynamic-ips-access-whm-without-constant-firewall-whitelisting.217922/

Comment: Because if i give this IP to him for the port access, this Ip might change and again, he will be needing to give me the required permission. Sorry as  this is my first time working in a corporate environment.

Comment: And moreover this is a private IP address, so i cant use this for the permission also. Or can i use ?. Will it work. ?

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is it possible to give an Azure instance a static public IP?

A: Your VM has static IP already.

[image]

Comment: But this is virtual not public.